# Deduction guide based on number of parameters passed to constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, constructor-overloading, ctad, deduction-guide

Here's something I'm trying that doesn't seem to work: I want to toggle a compile time switch based on how a class object is instantiated. If there's just one constructor argument, the `LengthOpt` should equal to `false`, otherwise to `true` (my implementation has more constructors where the switch should default to `true`.

I tried to create a deduction guide, but apparently it doesn't work if the template argument doesn't show up as a constructor argument (which is a real downer). Does anyone know a not-too-verbose solution to this problem?

[Code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gBspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXLaY9o4CdQ0ERRHRsXoK9Y3NOW0jvf0lZRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm27II8ShwEfYJhoAgls7e5iHx05nmKxXN/d3aAwj%2B2QCAaACp9mcXgARQ5mMwKVBsfahJJeAjggjnIzmMxHKx3b7fAiYFhJAxEl5uKKoTz7IKMYAEBAAeSSBC%2BvwMCgU4IRmAA%2BrsmFyCQB2PG3FFRWh4ZAgb77BU8tgCzkKCB/AFA0HzQ5i%2BWKg0jdAgFDLNFHNwW9HGkBUzxiJLAilWulGRks83HK1Gk2uWi4/UKkwiyGBpX8wVc9UCTXA4gg0jgvAAL35aPoDB1wfFBsNBBtaFRzuO1pNdoMtEdTGLblp9PdrJrpZAfoDdwNwdD%2BJDbZ%2BtyJJLJzwt5brbuZrKu4ZVQrVGrRWvjOoAtFP4crIwoLVQxEovptxQPSUxySPqbQxwyJ2zNthp5vo/8F3GE0nU3yCCu17yZ8LjhivEwfdxW%2BUI0RYJhQggeZRRzRV1wjVV9luCAzhgg8wwQ39uQsVCMUTM4Mzw4h5nQkCQw4RZaE4ABWXg/A4LRSFQThLUsaweRWNYYU2HhSAITRKMWABrEBNhFAA6Lh4gADnEyQNEkEUZI0eJ4hFfROEkejBOYzheAUEANH4wTFjgWAYEQU0SToWJyEoNAbPoOJBSMD9iC8BhhL4OgiWIQyICiXSolCBoAE9OD4xy2EEJkGFoCLGN4LAIKMcQktIfBiGqRwADdMEMjLMFUapUXWJiwI6XTpSiYhwo8LBdIxPAWEiyi%2BAMYAFAANTwTAAHcWUYNqZEEEQxHYKRRvkJQ1F03Q2gMIwUGsax9DwKJDMgRZUFZDJCuXI0jkhUx2MsLgRQMjocoyFwGHcTwWj0YJQgGUohjaFI0i6TJHomPJvoyGZBjiSZrpqbpRiaP7WnaTpaih4H3tB2wofGWGpkaJG5i4RZ4S4yb%2BOy9YeCo2idIyliOFUGT4mXeJJEBJbgH2CAAK8nUIDYqxLETXBCBIHi2n2DwnNiIX5l4ASktI0hRMkSQJLMJTJE2GSAE4zBkrX1fVmTNI4bTSFamjjIYpiqYMoyTJl0hzKss0UQIeyIEwfAiHOY02n4MbRHEKafZmlR1AyhbSH6uqkjasmODo0hzd4KmmVRJ39lQKh9hpumGaZwwWbZjyOdZ0Wkls4gJal0zFgQD4sDiaCDaNk2zd0y3bGt6WtFl0SzHViSRU1tSKjV3W5M2TYDc2CmLf0m2u7tyyICQNAsH5j2XZoDNWBJ3hA/G/3pEDxRg/m3JmZWs6bCqCG/Fd%2B70dyF7ihBkAaP1r6Cl%2B7I/ACD%2BfuxoYb84Y3Uhr0B%2BARr4/R6FjV6sxAH60xtDb%2BuREEALiG/PGyxVjrAeAwXYXgDgWlOM1LEt4CRmG2Hgp4FI3gYg%2BCwdk9wKGPAIcOY4yAHBhSSEBMh%2BI%2BG3HnICF86Jy7HRhGYGutBaCoH2P1EgtB0D7AQKgfq%2BwGjPDCssI4AAxbEvZvgAHoDH7CPEOCkBAuGMG3vsOomIWZiJ9CAM4FxEwWO4cwREcDRGbGhGBRhpiTxsMpOeS8DZPTQgAjw64HJZz7FoP1PkUQvBUHeJ8bs4pJTSllGGeJiTkmpJYI%2BWMoJ9hJKoDqEApTkl8mzGUzsuo4K5mbIWT0loSzYlCFMQQeBAmKP6oQZRRYMxXjTntAQrjiTHnJA0exPjxFNkca2DC7ZFSdgJCshUuSykFKKc%2BEpZSCIpjTHExgFSqlUBqWKOpIZEwZkuRYDM9TsxhjzAWM0TYOlPkMI4XpsiBknPHKMn62IFn5l9Pdf0yzbgdh7Pwg0RiTGTLMRaNxVjES2JcSYyxHjnheMYQaQRi59jAEwAQaCDSXmKn6ggWyrNHF4C5EkJgaxArVJMDRCweAak0UhKRGEPNOU1KhU0hUCLsoEBWAwc53LBWrXYjy3sIr9gIscS0psGKsRXLZRyrlcqrAKpDKCm0SzGm5hVWC00RYLRWmxJI6RILrUlkWRCxVIrxWSuley2Vl92WhmFas2FfYCVxmJaSvk1LCAFSZSyrMeoNm5ndcQKVZSZW6p9Qq/1QZA3fCSOcXKgS5TxrSO%2BNEuqfEaFdQqQlwiU2VrfMcu5%2BiexQsJEiwJFJRyuivB6KcWz8l0NYLsoR2p9irlvHEhJ2yB0MOODuWge4yEtv4d8TciKRiwXWfcZtIE7hgX2BBKCMF0k5Mnf27KrA05RG0NmM4BEMRETQmszNE68kpOnZe7QOIxRnCfaazCRyPz7ClWImSdaI30FZgwZcy4dSqveY62sqAr0SRJWSsim74XGLg1ar0JYkPaBQ6S8lCGP2EbQ0a8F6BIXkUhO1aisdp6J1Ynqzi2CeJmErjLESYlNgSQ0CPeI48uC8XVpIXWjdGN6Q4FbYynchIGw4/HVus85Oy3yv5W6kggA%3D%3D%3D):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

const char* str = "some input string";


template <bool LengthOpt>
class some_class
{
public:
    some_class(const char*) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << LengthOpt << std::endl;
    }
    some_class(const char*, size_t len) {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << LengthOpt << std::endl;
    }
};

template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;

int main()
{
    some_class A(str);
    some_class B(str, strlen(str));
}
```

**Errors**:

```
<source>:19:27: error: deduction guide template contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
                          ^
<source>:19:16: note: non-deducible template parameter 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
               ^
<source>:20:27: error: deduction guide template contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
                          ^
<source>:20:16: note: non-deducible template parameter 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
               ^
<source>:24:16: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'some_class'
    some_class A(str);
               ^
<source>:11:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
    some_class(const char*) {
    ^
<source>:19:27: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
                          ^
<source>:8:7: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'some_class<LengthOpt>' against 'const char *'
class some_class
      ^
<source>:14:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    some_class(const char*, size_t len) {
    ^
<source>:20:27: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
                          ^
<source>:25:16: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'some_class'
    some_class B(str, strlen(str));
               ^
<source>:14:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
    some_class(const char*, size_t len) {
    ^
<source>:20:27: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
                          ^
<source>:11:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
    some_class(const char*) {
    ^
<source>:8:7: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class some_class
      ^
<source>:19:27: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
                          ^
4 errors generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:19:27: error: deduction guide template contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
                          ^
<source>:19:16: note: non-deducible template parameter 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
               ^
<source>:20:27: error: deduction guide template contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
                          ^
<source>:20:16: note: non-deducible template parameter 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
               ^
<source>:24:16: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'some_class'
    some_class A(str);
               ^
<source>:11:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
    some_class(const char*) {
    ^
<source>:19:27: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
                          ^
<source>:8:7: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'some_class<LengthOpt>' against 'const char *'
class some_class
      ^
<source>:14:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    some_class(const char*, size_t len) {
    ^
<source>:20:27: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
                          ^
<source>:25:16: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'some_class'
    some_class B(str, strlen(str));
               ^
<source>:14:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
    some_class(const char*, size_t len) {
    ^
<source>:20:27: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'LengthOpt'
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
                          ^
<source>:11:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
    some_class(const char*) {
    ^
<source>:8:7: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
class some_class
      ^
<source>:19:27: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> some_class<false>;
                          ^
4 errors generated.
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a template parameter, just do:

```
some_class(const char *) -> some_class<false>;
some_class(const char *, size_t) -> some_class<true>;
```

Deduction guides are like functions, but all their template parameters must be deducible from their function parameters.

`template <bool LengthOpt> some_class(const char*) -> ...` turns into something like `template <bool LengthOpt> void foo(const char*)`, where `LengthOpt` is non-deducible.